# PowerAMC :delete prefix getters and setters

Tags: uml, powerdesigner

How can I delete the prefix getters and setters of class generated automatically by powerAMC

[image]

Comment: I don't know the tool, but those are stereotypes and they usually help code generators to identify that they belong to properties.

Comment: @ThomasKilian The tool is called [SAP PowerDesigner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerDesigner) except in France where it is called PowerACM in reference of its original name in the early 90's.

Comment: @Christophe They seem to make everything at SAP :-)

Comment: In `Tools > Display Preferences > Class`, I have an option to show (or hide) the Stereotype on Operations.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answers...